# Replacement for num_latest with class-based date-based generic views?

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

I've switched to Django 1.3 in order to get pagination for my date based generic views. This works fine, however there is a page where I want a specific number of items but do not want it paginated. For example, return the first 5 news entries.

In 1.2 we had num_latest which we could put in our info dict to get the latest items. This doesn't seem to exist with the new class-based generic views.

I could set paginate_by to 5 and just not use the pagination links in the template, but then people will still be able to see the old entries by punching in the url manually (which I don't want). Furthermore I don't want Django to set up pagination that I'm not going to use.

Edit: This is the urlconf line I'm currently using:

```
url(r'^$', 
    ArchiveIndexView.as_view(
        model = Entry,
        context_object_name = 'entry_list',
        template_name = 'news/news.html',
        date_field = 'published',
    ), name = 'archive_index'
),
```

Further edit: Attempting to override get_dated_queryset I've used this bit of code in conjunction with the urlconf as above but with the new view called:

```
class MainIndex(ArchiveIndexView):
    def get_dated_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()[:2]
```

I get almost the same error as mentioned in the comments:
Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding this instead:

`def get_dated_items(self):
    date_list, items, extra_context = super(MainIndex, self).get_dated_items()
    return (date_list, items[:2], extra_context)`

Note: this implementation may leave the `date_list` inconsistent with the `items` query set after the latter is sliced. I think that to fix that you would need to regenerate `date_list` too. see the implementation of BaseArchiveIndexView.get_dated_items in SVN for more details: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/dates.py.
Something like this might work:

`def get_dated_items(self):
    date_list, items, extra_context = super(MainIndex, self).get_dated_items()
    items = items[:2]
    date_list = self.get_date_list(items, 'year')
    if not date_list:
        items = items.none()
    return (date_list, items, extra_context)`

but if it works without this, I would not touch it because it looks too messy.

Comment: Sadly not. I have already tried simply slicing the queryset like so: queryset = Entry.objects.all()[:5], however this gives me the following error: "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.", presumably because there is some more stuff done after the slice.

Comment: are you using a derivative of BaseDayArchiveView mixin?

Comment: Not for that url. I've edited my original post to show the urlconf I'm currently using for the relevant view.

Comment: Hmm. That looks like it would work, but it seems very messy and by the looks of it I'd be better off just either making a custom view or using paginate_by and just not using the pagination. Probably less code, too. I'll mark this as answered if nobody comes up with a better idea. Thanks.

Comment: whatever works for you. I think subclassing is the design approach that django is aiming for. in other words, if you want to extend a view's functionality, you subclass it, thus creating a custom view. see for example here: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#extending-generic-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#extending-generic-views)

Comment: I've tried out this method (which does seem like the "right" way to do it). I started by just overriding the function completely but even that won't work, error as above.

Comment: try instead overriding get_queryset() but in your implementation call the base implementation first an then slice it. it is just a matter of finding the right place to slice the query set.

Comment: I tried overriding get_queryset() earlier, and same error. Can you elaborate what you mean about calling the base implementation? I'm not sure I get what you mean. Can you give a line or two of code?

Comment: It seems to work fine as is, but my dataset is very small. I'll keep this in mind in case I run into problems, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem myself. I've found that using ListView (instead of ArchiveIndexView) for this saved me time and hassle.

For your first chunk of code, the difference would be:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


url(r'^$', 
    ListView.as_view(
        model = Entry,
        context_object_name = 'entry_list',
        template_name = 'news/news.html',
        queryset=Entry.objects.all().order_by("-published")[:2],
    ), name = 'archive_index'
),
```